# Изменить CSS при клике на ссылку

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть сайт на wordpress, можно ли как-то сделать так, чтобы при клике на **любую уже существующую или будущую** ссылку (внутреннюю или внешнюю) становился видимым определённый div?

```css
#gp-page-loader.gp-remove-loader {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Менялся на

```css
#gp-page-loader.gp-remove-loader {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: vivsible;
}
```

Comment: Это вопрос не по WordPress совсем.

Comment: @Jean-Claude, причем тут jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> при клике на любую уже существующую или будущую ссылку (внутреннюю или
> внешнюю)

Именно так

```js
var link = document.querySelector("a");
var loader = document.getElementsByClassName('gp-remove-loader');
link.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  //console.log("Добавили");
  loader[0].setAttribute("style", "opacity:1; visibility:visible");
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
#gp-page-loader .gp-remove-loader {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Ссылка</a><br>
<div id="gp-page-loader">
  <div class="gp-remove-loader"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Меня учили, что event.preventDefault(); следует писать в первую очередь, а затем уже прочие действия. Я неправ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const a = document.querySelector('.link');

a.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const div = document.querySelector('div');
  div.classList.add('visible');
});
```

```css
div {
  opacity: 0;
}

.visible {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="link">Ссылка</a>
<div>Когда-то невидимый блок</div>
```

Или можно так:

```js
const a = document.querySelector('.link');

a.addEventListener('click', () => {
  try {
    const className = 'invisible';
    const div = document.querySelector(`.${className}`);
    div.classList.remove(className);
  } catch {}
});
```

```css
.invisible {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="link">Ссылка</a>
<div class="invisible">Когда-то невидимый блок</div>
```

Вот гораздо более модернизированный вариант. Здесь ссылки с блоками генерируются динамически:

```js
const objOfLinks = {
  link1: {
    content: "Ссылка №1",
    div: {
      content: "Когда-то невидимый блок"
    }
  },
  link2: {
    content: "Ссылка №2",
    div: {
      content: "Когда-то невидимый блок"
    }
  },
  link3: {
    content: "Ссылка №3",
    div: {
      content: "Когда-то невидимый блок"
    }
  }
}

function createBlock(obj, cb) {
  const block = document.createElement('div');
  block.classList.add('block');
  let i = 0;
  for (const elem in obj) {
    i++;
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    a.textContent = obj[elem].content;
    a.dataset.num = i;
    a.classList.add('link');
    a.href = '#';
    const div = cb(obj[elem].div.content, i);
    block.appendChild(a);
    block.appendChild(div);
  }
  document.body.appendChild(block);
}

function createDiv(content, i) {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  div.classList.add(`div${i}`);
  div.textContent = content;
  return div;
}

createBlock(objOfLinks, createDiv);

document.querySelectorAll('.link').forEach(elem => {
  elem.addEventListener('click', ev => {
    const number = ev.target.dataset.num;
    document.querySelector(`div.div${number}`).classList.add('invisible');
  });
});
```

```css
.invisible {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но это можно использовать если как-то добавить ко всем ссылкам класс link, а хотелось бы избежать такого

Comment: Тогда просто `const a = document.querySelector('a');` и можно не добавлять класс

Comment: Спасибо еще раз. Извините за наглость, не подскажете еще, можно ли как-то перечислить несколько классов .link , .link2 , .link3 ?

Comment: @Garik, Да, с помощью цикла

Comment: @Garik, как я понял, в вашем случае используется несколько ссылок и блоков к ним, чуть позже приложу пару решений в свой ответ

Comment: Ага. И если на странице есть 2 и более ссылки с классом link, то срабатывает только для первой

Comment: @Garik, пожалуйста, посмотрите мой ответ, я добавил вариант для нескольких ссылок

Comment: Да, спасибо, смог применить ваш ответ для отдельных ссылок. Но сам вопрос был именно про все ссылки на сайте, поэтому выбирать ваш как решение будет неправильно...